# Hyperlinks in zref

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, zref

I use the great package `zref` to create my own referencing system. Can I make hyperlinks for pdftex (and tex4ht)?

See the following code. I'd like to make the `\showref` command clickable, so that I jump to the place where I use the `\setdest` command. Is this (easily) possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{zoo}
\zref@newprop{animal}{\currentanimal}
\zref@addprop{zoo}{animal}
\newcommand\setdest[2]{\def\currentanimal{#2}\zref@labelbylist{#1}{zoo}}
\newcommand\showref[1]{\zref@extract{#1}{animal}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{My favorite pets}
\setdest{label}{Cat}

See the animal \showref{label}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the `zref` manual, `hyperref` is left as a future work.

However, you could at least use the normal `\phantomsection` trick, and another label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{zoo}
\zref@newprop{animal}{\currentanimal}
\zref@addprop{zoo}{animal}
\newcommand\setdest[2]{\def\currentanimal{#2}\zref@labelbylist{#1}{zoo}\phantomsection\label{zref:#1}}
\newcommand\showref[1]{\hyperref[zref:#1]{\zref@extract{#1}{animal}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{My favorite pets}
\lipsum[1]

\setdest{label}{Cat}
Cat goes here.

\lipsum[2]

\section{Other}
See the animal \showref{label}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question, but it seems to be the most explicit one on the "status" of `zref`'s support for `hyperref` (even if not the only one), and the accepted answer makes the claim that "it is left as future work", which is not quite correct.  It is true that there is no user documentation for `zref-hyperref` and that it's implementation leaves "UNFINISHED :-(" as a caveat.  But the module *is functional*, and loading it does provide the `anchor` property (and includes it to the `main` property list) which can be used to construct an hyperlink to the reference with standard `hyperref` user macros.  So, even if things are not quite polished and documented, they work:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{zref-hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newlist{zoo}
\zref@newprop{animal}{\currentanimal}
\zref@addprop{zoo}{animal}
\zref@addprop{zoo}{anchor}
\newcommand\setdest[2]{\def\currentanimal{#2}\zref@labelbylist{#1}{zoo}}
\newcommand\showref[1]{%
  \hyperlink{\zref@extractdefault{#1}{anchor}{}}{\zref@extract{#1}{animal}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{My favorite pets}
\setdest{label}{Cat}

See the animal \showref{label}.
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

I haven't tested `tex4ht`, but I'd presume it should work as long as `\hyperlink` does (hence, pending on `hyperref`, not quite on `zref`).

Comment: I've tested it in TeX4ht and it doesn't fail, it produces the Cat text, but link is wrong. It seems that `zref` cannot set correct link destination to the section in this case.

Comment: Hi @michal.h21! Long time! I hope you are doing well. I think this may be due to the non-standard way the label is being set (in `\setdest`). Let me try with a more standard section link.

Comment: @michal.h21 I've tested here, and the anchor is correct even for `\setdest` (it points to the section counter though, as expected here). However, `make4ht` points to `#Doc-Start` (probably also what you saw there). Does `\hyperlink` work in general for `tex4ht`, I mean, regardless of `zref`?

Comment: Hi, yes long time :) I am well, I hope you too. `\hyperlink` works with `\hypertarget` with TeX4ht. It seems that `\currentHref` that `hyperref` uses is not set correctly with TeX4ht for sections.

Comment: Mhm, I don't know why that would make a difference, but I'm never surprised by `tex4ht` needing special handling for things. The `anchor` is stored by `hyperref` for standard labels as well, it is just usually not the most common (user facing) way to refer to it. Would you like a sample document to test?

Comment: TeX4ht definitely inteferes with Hyperref and vice versa, as both of them patches sections and other stuff that can be referenced with `\label`. Simpler testing document would be nice.

Comment: @michal.h21 I did come up with a simple document using anchor and `\hyperlink`, but it worked with `make4ht`... See https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/890a600eb8362800dcf3d2528c7f4fc8. Do you get why there might be a difference from the case here?

Comment: @michal.h21 My first guess here is that the work done by `tex4ht` with `\newlabel` in the aux file is not done also for `\zref@newlabel`.