# hyperlink pointing options for multiline equations with centered labels

Tags: hyperref, split, hyperlink, pointer

I have a split equation as in the MWE below. However, when I click on the corresponding hyperlink, it directs/ points me to the text line right before the first equation line. I would like it to point to the first equation line. Is that possible? If, how? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &= B\\
C &= D\\
E &= F\\
G &= H = I = \\
& \quad = J = K
\end{split}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\lipsum

Insertion of~\eqref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is strange. For me, the reference points to the line that contains the equation number.

Comment: could be. I have my multiline equations inserted in a wider document with a lot of packages and options. Still, in that document all hyperlinks associated to single line equations work fine, i.e. they point to the corresponding labels, which in the case of single line equations are always the first equation line of course. Still, the basic question remains even in the simple MWE above: How to make an hyperlink point to the first line of a multiline equation, while keeping the label vertically centered?

Comment: a lot of packages includes cleverref, so it could be that there is some kind of conflict as in this discussion: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210480/…. In the abovementioned wider document I also have multiline equations within align environments, with each equation containing a label in that case, and the hyperlinks also point correctly to the label. For some reason, the label for the split environment is giving trouble. Is there any other environment that centers labels for multiline equations?

Comment: If there was an alternative to the split environment for having centered labels in multiline equations, I should probably try it, and first make sure the hyperlink points to the label, before finally solving the original question, which is to move the pointer to the first equation line..............

Comment: Your question gets with every comment more unclear. Does your example show the problem you have or not? And where do you want the link to point to?

Comment: my comments just indicate that I actually have two problems, one of them being the one that started this discussion. So, coming back to the original problem in the MWE above, I want the link to point to the first equation line, and not to the centered label

Comment: I further improved the MWE for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87341/73317) for the starting point, to make equation references that point to:

- the first equation line in an `equation` environment;
- the current line in an `align` or `gather` environment (other environments can be easily added, see below).

Note that due to the different times at which the `equation` counter is incremented depending on the `amsmath` environment used, my code has to distinguish between two cases. However, by detection of the current environment, it offers you an “automatic mode” where normally, you as a user don't have to distinguish between the two cases. So, here are the two options:

1. Automatic choice of the custom labelling command: always use `\myeqlabel` to create an equation label;
2. Manual choice of the custom labelling command:

   - use `\myeqlabelnoauto*` inside environments such as `align` and `gather` for which the correct value of the `equation` counter for a given line is obtained *after* the `\\` command that ends a line (i.e., the counter is one unit too small at the point where `\myeqlabelnoauto*` has to be called in order for the reference to point to the line we want);
   - use `\myeqlabelnoauto` when the `equation` counter is already correct at the point where `\myeqlabelnoauto` is called (normally, all other cases).

Automatic mode (via the `\myeqlabel` command) knows the `align` and `gather` environments as requiring “special handling” (corresponding to what `\myeqlabelnoauto*` does). If you discover other environments that need the same special handling (which would manifest as off-by-one reference numbers), add them to the following line of my code:

```latex
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_euclides_special_envs_seq { align, gather }
```

Here is the code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_euclides_special_envs_seq
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_euclides_special_envs_seq { align, gather }

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \euclides_if_special_env:n #1
  { T, F, TF }
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \g_euclides_special_envs_seq {#1}
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \euclides_if_special_env:n { V }
  { T, F, TF }

\NewDocumentCommand \ifeuclspecialenv { m m m }
  {
    \euclides_if_special_env:VTF #1 {#2} {#3}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter

\zref@newlist{mylist}
\zref@newprop{equation}[??]{0}
\zref@addprop{mylist}{equation}

\newcommand*{\my@set@zref@equation@prop}[1]{%
  \zref@setcurrent{equation}{#1}%
}

% Manual labelling command: depending on the enclosing environment, one has to
% use the normal or the star form.
\newcommand*{\myeqlabelnoauto}{%
  \@ifstar{\@myeqlabelnoauto{+1}}{\@myeqlabelnoauto{}}%
}

\newcommand*{\@myeqlabelnoauto}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \edef\my@tmp@eqnum{\number\numexpr \value{equation} #1 \relax}%
    \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\my@set@zref@equation@prop\expandafter{\my@tmp@eqnum}%
  \phantomsection\label{zref:#2}%
  \zref@wrapper@babel\zref@labelbylist{#2}{mylist}%
}

% Automatic detection of the appropriate labelling command: the code will use
% either \myeqlabelnoauto or \myeqlabelnoauto* depending on the enclosing
% environment.
\newcommand*{\myeqlabel}{%
  \ifeuclspecialenv{\@currenvir}{\myeqlabelnoauto*}{\myeqlabelnoauto}%
}

% Referencing command that goes with the above labelling commands.
\newcommand*{\myeqref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[zref:#1]{%
    \textup{\tagform@{\zref@wrapper@babel\zref@extract{#1}{equation}}}}%
  \zref@refused{#1}% uses \zref@wrapper@babel internally
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

The \verb|equation| environment increments the \verb|equation| counter at the
beginning of the environment; use either \verb|\myeqlabel| or
\verb|\myeqlabelnoauto| there. This example shows a \verb|split| environment
inside \verb|equation|:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    \myeqlabel{some-eq}
    A &= B\\
    C &= D + E\\
      & \quad + F + G
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

The \verb|align| environment increments the \verb|equation| counter
\emph{after} the \verb|\\| that ends a line; use either \verb|\myeqlabel| or
\verb|\myeqlabelnoauto*|. This example shows an \verb|align| environment:
%
\begin{align}
  \myeqlabel{other-eq-a} a &= b + c+ d + e   & u - v &= f + f'\\
  \myeqlabel{other-eq-b}   &= g              &     z &= h\\
  \myeqlabel{other-eq-c}   &= i              &     t &= j
\end{align}

The \verb|gather| environment is similar to \verb|align| as far as the macros
developed here are concerned; use either \verb|\myeqlabel| or
\verb|\myeqlabelnoauto*|:
\begin{gather}
\myeqlabel{gather-eq-a} a_1 = b_1 + c_1\\
\myeqlabel{gather-eq-b} a_2 = b_2 + c_2 - d_2 + e_2
\end{gather}
Pointers to equations \myeqref{some-eq}, \myeqref{other-eq-a},
\myeqref{other-eq-b}, \myeqref{other-eq-c}, \myeqref{gather-eq-a}
and \myeqref{gather-eq-b}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a lot frougon! It does work! However, I was hoping to avoid such ad hoc solutions and to have way more synthetic code. Is there no simpler alternative?

Comment: It's the only way I know... and not difficult to use. Once the commands are defined, you just need to call them instead of `\label` and `\eqref`.

Comment: I have another related problem! I actually would need the hyperlink to point to the first line of a split equation inside an align, not an equation environment. Would it be possible to adjust the solution you proposed earlier?

Comment: Dear @Euclides, two persons took the care to answer your question; you upvoted none of the answers, didn't mark any as accepted either (you know, this is done by clicking on the “tick” mark left of your preferred answer), and now you come back to us eighteen days later and ask a new question in the comments. We are not your slaves. :-)

Comment: sorry about the upvoting. I thought some external entity had the authority to do that. Already upvoted. As for the 18 days time interval, I'm sorry. It's just that I changed all equation environments in my document to align environments as these latter offer some (alignment, what else? :-D) advantages, and I'm not sure about how to adapt your solution to the "new circumstances". I could probably get there on my own, but I have currently absolutely no time to do research on .tex, so I would be very grateful if I could get any help on this issue.

Comment: @Euclides All right. `align`-like environments don't update the `equation` counter at the same time as `equation`; I have updated my answer accordingly, so please read it again. You have accepted my answer now; that's better and means it is the best answer given here for your question, according to you. But you should also upvote both answers here in my opinion (i.e., click above the score, currently  0), because I think they are both helpful, and this is the normal way to say “thank you” on this site. Good luck with your work.

Comment: Thanks a lot frougon! I'll follow your recommendation and upvote both answers ASAP. Best regards, Euclides

Answer (score 1):

You can locally or generally change the amount the link is raised by hyperref:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Some preliminary text...
%also possible, default is 1 \baselineskip.
%\renewcommand\HyperRaiseLinkDefault{2\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\HyperRaiseLinkHook{\setlength\HyperRaiseLinkLength{2\baselineskip}}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &= B \\
C &= D = E = \\
& \quad = F = G
\end{split}
\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

Insertion of~\eqref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Much more synthetic code than that of frogoun. Not sure yet if as clean. Thanks a lot Ulrike!

Comment: Well my code is shorter, but also more "manual".